# Is there a use of swearing language in Star Wars movies, novels, comics or videogames?

Tags: star-wars

I was always under the impression (or never encountered) that swearing and offensive language is not present in the Star Wars universe, yet in **Andor** season 1, episode 3, Linus Mosk uses a word that could be considered offensive also there is a use of the word *bastards*, I'm pretty sure no swearing is present in movies but was there any previous occurrence in novels, comics, video games, … whether Legends or Canon.

Comment: Would you consider Obi-Wan's "D***-fool crusade" in A New Hope swearing?

Comment: It might, but I was talking about type of language that we do not see on national TV like the word said which is considered vulgar.

Comment: Which word? I haven't seen Andor.

Comment: I do not want trouble here but it is the equivalent to **poop**

Comment: Literally everything R2D2 says. That droid is pure filth; basically the Derek and Clive of the Star Wars galaxy.

Comment: Are you counting words spoken in alien languages but subtitled in English or just spoken in English. (Also would "slag" count in it's usage by Sebulba to Anakin?)

Comment: No, unless the subtitles explicitly says so.

Comment: So, would you count slag??

Comment: I think you impression is correct. Star Wars was an innocent movie. It was also a family movie. It was a fairy-tale set in space. It didn't go for gangsta nastiness ...

Comment: So why the downvotes please? and where slag was used?

Comment: After the altercation between Sebulba and Jar-Jar, Anakin stands up to him - Sebulba says "what did you say, slave slag?" in Dugeese.  (Subtitled).

Comment: @JiminyCricket. - are those the official subtitles. Also, the use is far more to be in reference to the sort of slag (scum) you get on the top of molten metal than a derogatory term used against women

Comment: https://www.cbr.com/swear-word-first-andor-star-wars/

Comment: Not a single one, it's frakking ridiculous

Comment: @Valorum I was going from [the script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/scripts/star-wars-episode-i-the-phantom-menace-1999.pdf). The previous part isn't labelled as subtitled, but specifically that bit is. I need to watch it again to be sure. I agree about the usage, but the word origin and echo of connotation is the same even if the usage is unfamiliar. I'm not sure what the OP is after.

Comment: OP, are you asking for specifically real-world English-language cussing, such as in the one episode of Andor with a scatological reference? Or are you asking for in-universe made-up cuss  words like fierfek, kriffing, karabast, shebs? "Damn", "hell", and "bastard" have been used before Andor was released but those are kind of cussing-lite since they're fairly PG words.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. - I believe that's a fan-written version of the script based on the June 6 shooting script that was previously available in .Doc

Comment: In one of the newer films Luke tells R2D2 off for swearing

Comment: "*Why you stuck-up, half-witted, scruffy-looking, nerf herder!*" is pretty much in-universe swearing language, right?

Comment: E chu ta! -How Rude!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Canon

The 2020 novel *[Queen's Peril](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Queen%27s_Peril)* by E.K. Johnston contains a canon example of an English-language swearword ("***shit***") being used, predating *Andor* by more than two years.

> The treaty was, in Sio Bibble’s professional opinion, **a pile of shaak
> shit.** Naboo would be indenturing itself to the Trade Federation’s
> whims and stood to gain absolutely nothing from the arrangement. They
> couldn’t possibly expect the Queen to sign it.

---

### Legends

Moving down the canon scale, Han solo also refers to some aliens as "***buggers***" in the short novel [*Jedi Prince #4: Mission to Mount Yoda*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mission_from_Mount_Yoda) (1993)

> “That must be **the sound those buggers make** when they’re starving and smell food,” Han said, firing his laserblaster at the ones that were behind them.

Bossk is "***pissed off***" in [*The Bounty Hunter Wars #1: The Mandalorian Armor*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mandalorian_Armor) (1998)

> With a single foreclaw, Bossk pointed to the sterile bandage running
> diagonally across his chest, from one shoulder and under the opposite
> arm. “It really hurt,” he said, still smiling. “But it didn’t kill me.
> You should know how hard our species is to get rid of. And
> also-whatever doesn’t destroy one of us just **makes us that much more
> pissed off.”**

Mirta Gev (a Mandalorian bounty hunter) calls Tahiri Veila, a female Sith apprentice a "***dung-sucking slut***" in [*Star Wars - Legacy of the Force #9: Invincible*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Force:_Invincible).

> That inspired Mirta to raise her head. “Go ahead, **you dung-sucking
> dark side slut!** See what happens.”

Comment: Also from the canon films, TLJ introduces a "big-ass door", and in Solo Lando starts to say "oh ssshhh—"